# Esconder e mostrar o cabeçalho de um listview quando rolado

Tags: java, android, xml, listview

Estou desenvolvendo um *app* para Android usando o Android Studio, e quero um `listview` com cabeçalho onde  o cabeçalho seja ocultado quando a lista seja rolada para baixo, e ele apareça quando rolado para cima independente da posição da barra de rolagem. Esse mecanismo existe na tela de *feeds* do Facebook como exemplo.

Answer (score 1):

Você pode criar uma view como header da sua lista e, ao reconhecer o scroll, esconder/mostrar essa view.

```
final HeaderView header = new HeaderView(getActivity(), json);
mListView.addHeaderView(header);
setOnScrollListener(new OnScrollListener(){
    public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }
    public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        if(scrollState == 0) {
            Log.i("a", "scrolling stopped...");

            if (view.getId() == mListView.getId()) {
                final int currentFirstVisibleItem = mListView.getFirstVisiblePosition();
                if (currentFirstVisibleItem > mLastFirstVisibleItem) {
                    header.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                } else if (currentFirstVisibleItem < mLastFirstVisibleItem) {
                    header.setVisibility(View.GONE)
                }
                mLastFirstVisibleItem = currentFirstVisibleItem;
            } 
        }
     }
 });
```

Comment: Essa resposta não é a exata solução do problema, mas é bem próximo. Usei o métodos descritos para alterar a margem um Frame/Cabeçalho fora da lista, fazendo com que ele escondesse quando rolado para cima, e aparecendo quando rolado para baixo. Não funcionou com precisão pois a alteração da margem só ocorre quando muda o primeiro item visível. Quero algo mais preciso. Tentei usar o getScrollY e getPositionScrollBar mas só retorna 0. Ainda não esta como eu quero.

Answer (score 0):

Você cria uma view que vai ser o seu cabeçalho e dá um addHeaderView:

```
    HeaderView header = new HeaderView(getActivity(), json);
    mListView.addHeaderView(header);
```

Comment: 0 Método addHeaderView pede como parâmetro um View, e não um HeaderView. E da onde vem o "json"?. Crie uma View para o header e coloquei null no lugar do jason, atribui e funcionou, mas o efeito a qual explique na pergunta não aparece. Pode dar mais detalhes?

Comment: Amigo, qualquer tipo de view (elemento que vai na tela) descende de View, por isso a resposta do @paulokhouri.

Comment: Sim, eu havia suspeitado. A declaração de um tipo HeaderView poderia necessitar de uma biblioteca que eu desconheço e que daria o efeito que eu preciso. Mas o principal item da questão ainda está sem solução. Por isso eu pedi mais detalhes.